# Linq count on a secondary grouping criteria

Tags: c#, linq

I need help with a linq query which is driving me nut.
i have a Datatable with the following data :

Item1 / child1 / 10 more columns

Item1 / child2 / 10 more columns

Item2 / child1 / 10 more columns

Item3 / child1 / 10 more columns

Item3 / child2 / 10 more columns

i would like the folowing result :

Item1 / count of child / child1 / 1 column

Item1 / count of child / child2 / 1 column

Item2 / count of child / child1 / 1 column
 etc ....

In my query, item is "artiste", child is "album" and 1 column is "disque"

```
 var tre_res = from res in Globals.ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                      orderby res.Field<string>("artiste")
                      group res by new { arti = res.Field<string>("artiste"), alb = res.Field<string>("album") } into groupings
                      select new artisteYalbum { artiste = groupings.Key.arti, album = groupings.Key.alb,  countealb = groupings.Count() };
```

I have 2 issues : i cant understand the result of the count, it is not the number of child ... also, i do not know how to select the additional column.

Here is the artisteYalbum class :

```
   public class artisteYalbum
{
    public string artiste { get; set; }
    public string album { get; set; }
    public string disque { get; set; }
    public int countealb { get; set; }
}
```

Eventually, i want to be able to populate a tree view and put the number of album (the count) at the end of the artiste name (with a bracket). This query will allow me to put that count right away without having to calculate anything.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example it seems you don't actually want to group your database items, since **item1** apears twice in the results. It seems you need to count albuns per artist, and append that value to `artisteYalbum` instances.

Try this instead:

```
var items = (from res in Globals.ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
            orderby res.Field<string>("artiste")
            select new artisteYalbum
            {
                artiste = res.Field<string>("artiste"),
                album = res.Field<string>("album")
                // additional properties here...
            }).ToList();

// gets the count of albums for each artist
var counts = items.GroupBy(x => x.artiste)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());

// fills countealb property value
foreach (var item in items)
    item.countealb = counts[item.artiste];
```

Comment: thanks Thomas, actually i want the count not the index. Eventually, i want to populate a treeview with 2 levels : Artiste and Album. The count will be used to add the number of albums at the end of the artist name (like "artist xx (3)"), the add column will help me to add an icon for each of the album

Comment: Hey Thomas, it works great until the filling of the count back in the "items" on the very last line. The counts[item.Artiste] brings the correct value, but the "item.countealb" for some reasons stays at 0 !

Comment: That's strange. Try putting a breakpoint in the code and debug the "item.countealb" assignment for your last item, to find out why it's not working

Comment: I just saw from the answer edit history that you already found the solution, it was only a matter of appending ".ToList()" at the end of the `items` query! I updated the answer accordingly